# SCSS errors when I try and make it into CSS

Tags: css

So I tried to compile my SCSS code, and it doesn't work for some weird reason. I've used VSC compilers and even a lot of online ones too. None of the seem to work, and every time I try and view it, it always breaks and goes all ewy and messy.

I've used cssportal, jsonformatter (they have a scss to css thing), vsc plugins for compiling it. D:

```
// variables
$blue-dark: #1C202A;
$blue: #2D3543;
$blue-light: #737D9C;

$red-dark: #C0180C;
$red: #E0280C;
$red-light: #F0382C;

$gray-light: #c1c1c1;
$gray: #969696;

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  background-color: $blue-dark;
  background-image: url(http://www.cfdesigner.com/codepen/rocket-page-bkg.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  letter-spacing: (0.5/16)+rem;
  line-height: (24/16)+rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
}

h1, p {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: (40/16)+rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: (2/16)+rem;
}

p {
  font-size: (16/16)+rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#container {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 525px;
  width: 320px;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    
    &:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
  
  a {
    border: solid 2px #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 1rem;
    padding: calc(1rem - 2px);
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
    &:hover {
      background: $blue-light;
      border-color: $blue-light;
    }
  }
  
  .primary {
    background-color: $red;
    border-color: $red;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 4px $red-dark;
    color: #fff;
    
    &:hover {
      background: $red-light;
      border-color: $red-dark;
    }
    
    &:active {
      background: $red-dark;
    }
  }
  
  .minor {
    border: none;
    color: $gray-light;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    
    &:hover {
      background: none;
      color: #fff;
    }
  }
  
  .disabled {
    background: none;
    border: solid 2px $gray;
    color: $gray;
    //opacity: 0.5;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}

form .field {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

form input[type='password'],
form input[type='text'],
form input[type='submit'] {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

form input[type='password'],
form input[type='text'] {
  background-color: #3b4148;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

form input[type='password']:focus,
form input[type='password']:hover,
form input[type='text']:focus,
form input[type='text']:hover {
  background-color: #434a52;
  outline: none;
}

form input[type='submit'] {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding: calc(1rem - 2px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  
  &:focus {
    background: $red-light;
    outline: none;
  }
  
  &:active {
    background: $red-dark;
  }
}

form label {
  background-color: #363b41;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  fill: #fff;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 2rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#footer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  font-size: (14/16)+em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  
  ul {
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  li {
    border-left: solid 1px $blue-light;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 1em;
    
    &:first-child {
      border: none;
    }
  }
  
  a {
    color: $blue-light;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    &:hover {
      color: $gray-light;
    }
  }
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: `(0.5/16)+rem` is an invalid syntax. You should use either `0.5rem / 16` or `(0.5/16) * 1rem`. Btw, using `/` as division is deprecated, use `math.div()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try using npm packages and also check for possible typos in the path url

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).